# How find this $5xy\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}$ can write the sum of Four 5-th powers of positive integers.

Tags: number-theory

> Find  all positive integer $x,y$ such
> $$5xy\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}$$ can write
> the sum of Four  5-th powers of positive integers.In other words: there exst $a,b,c,d\in N^{+}$ such
> $$5xy\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}=a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5$$

This problem is from Math competition simulation test.I seach this problem and  found  this problem background is Euler's sum of powers conjecture.can see [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture)

maybe this problem is not hard.because is from competition.
since
$$5xy\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}=5xy(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
so $$x^2+y^2=m^2$$
$$x=3,y=4,m=5$$
and $$x=(a'^2-b'^2),y=2a'b',m=a'^2+b'^2$$
then I can't it
Thank you for you help .

Comment: Well,first of all,$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ must be an integer.

Comment: They look suspiciously like pythagorean triplets,don't they?Oh wait. . . .

Comment: Note that $a$ and $b$ must have opposite parity.It isn't immediately useful,but keeping this information in mind will prevent making any errors in the future.Besides,have you actually tried and substitue the value of the variables $x,y$(in terms of $a,b$) in the original equation?

Comment: Substitute the values of x and y in the original equation and then try and see what you can get.It will probably help.Also,since our equation is symmetric in x and y,assume without loss of generality that $a$ is odd and then try parity.I am not saying this will yield the solutions,but it might help.

Comment: "maybe this problem is not hard.It's from a competition".haha,contest problems aren't hard?

Comment: It's interesting that the thing has degree $5$ as a polynomial in $x$ and $y$... Perhaps start with the general form of a Pythagorean triple: let $x=d(m^2-n^2)$ and $y=2dmn$, with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $m,n$ are of opposite parity.

Comment: I wonder if looking at the equation modulo 11 will help.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help. Using what you said, namely:

$x^2+y^2=k^2$, with $x=m^2-n^2$, $y=2mn$ then the left hand side of the equation becomes:
$LHS=10(m^9n-mn^9+2m^7n^3-2m^3n^7)$

Since $RHS\equiv 0$ modulo 2 and modulo 5 then we have $a+b+c+d\equiv 0 \mod{2}$ and $a+b+c+d\equiv 0 \mod{5}$

Comment: Note that "odd modulo 5" makes no sense, i.e. $(0, 0, 1, 4)\equiv (0, 0, 1, 9)\pmod{5}$, the latter being acceptable $\pmod{10}$.

Comment: @jpvee Thank you. I removed that part.

Comment: @Test,I don't understand how you derive the final line of your ans.